# Assemble 0.6.0: How do I apply multiple templates to my source files?

Tags: assemble

I want Assemble to take my source files (/src/hbs/*.hbs) and create two separate files (e.g. one with a header, footer and nav, and another with just the code snippet). I've created two templates (default(full page) and empty (just a wrapper)). I'm using gulp assemble and it looks like this:

```
gulp.task('assemble', function () {
  assemble.layouts(paths.templates.layouts);
  assemble.partial(paths.templates.partials);

  gulp.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'default' }))
    .pipe(prettify())
    .pipe(rename({basename:'index', extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.www));
});

gulp.task('snippet', function(){
  assemble.layouts(paths.templates.layouts);
  assemble.partial(paths.templates.partials);

  gulp.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'empty' }))
    .pipe(prettify())
    .pipe(rename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.www));

});
```

When I run gulp both files are wrapped in the default template. What am I missing?

Comment: I needed to define the Assemble layout and partials outside of the tasks. Not sure why I didn't try that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The code in Brandon Merritt's example was based on Assemble's 0.6.0 beta API.

This is how you would accomplish this in assemble now (as of v0.17.0):

```
var assemble = require('assemble');
var app = assemble();


// use a task for loading collections, so we can ensure views
// are loaded before `src` files, or re-loaded when watch is triggered
app.task('load', function(cb) {
  app.layouts(paths.templates.layouts);
  app.partial(paths.templates.partials);
  cb();
});

app.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
  // with assemble or gulp, you need to return the stream
  // or call the callback to signal task completion
  return app.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(rename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(app.dest(paths.build.www));
});

app.task('snippet', ['load'], function() {
  return app.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(app.renderFile({ layout: 'default' }))
    .pipe(rename({basename:'index', extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(app.dest(paths.build.www));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to define the Assemble components higher in the process and it fixed it.

```
assemble.layouts(paths.templates.layouts);
assemble.partial(paths.templates.partials);

gulp.task('assemble', function () {
  gulp.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'empty' }))
    .pipe(rename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.www));
});

gulp.task('snippet', function () {
  gulp.src(paths.sources.handlebars)
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'default' }))
    .pipe(rename({basename:'index', extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.www));
});
```